# Disable submit button if validation true (jQuery Validation Engine)

Tags: jquery, validation, button, jquery-validation-engine

I'm using jQuery Validation Engine (https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) to validate my form. I want to disable submit button to prevent multiple submits if validation is true. I couldn't achieve this with callback functions.

Answer (score 1):

I always do this trick

```
$('#yourform').submit(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('blockSubmit')) return false;
    $(this).addClass('blockSubmit');
    /*
     * organizing data, requesting, responding, et cetra cetra...
     */
    $(this).removeClass('blockSubmit');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically do this:

```
$('#theform').submit(function() {
    $('#submitbutton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Of course if you are doing any onsubmit validation that fails you have to reenable the button:

```
$('#submitbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
```